# Sphinx and autodoc: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import + mock has unsupported operand type

Tags: python, mocking, python-sphinx, autodoc

I am trying to build the documentation for my project (https://github.com/pyMatJ/S4Utils) using sphinx and autodoc, targeting RtD eventually (https://s4utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

So far I managed to make the whole project installable and I think my setup.py is in order. However, I cannot get sphinx to properly generate the documentation with autodoc. I set up a clean python3.6 venv using virtualenvwrapper, installed only sphinx and my package and tried to compile the doc (`make html`). The pages with manual input (installation etc.) work fine, as well as one autodocumented module (https://s4utils.readthedocs.io/en/latest/epsInterpolator.html).
However, the bulk of the autodoc job is still missing (two other modules should be documented), and I get a bunch of warnings about autodoc not being able to import the module. Eventually it looks like it boils down to two main errors:

> hbar_eV = h_eV/(2*np.pi) 
> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'Mock'

from one module importing numpy in its preamble and using it to define a variable

as well as

> numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
> for both modules.

The errors are reproduced both from RtD and a clean venv. I checked that only one version of numpy is installed (latest, 1.19.1). I use a `conf.py` file importing mock, and mocking the relevant (I suppose) modules:

```
from unittest.mock import Mock as MagicMock
MOCK_MODULES = ['numpy', 'matplotlib.pyplot', 'matplotlib.gridspec', 'matplotlib.widgets', 'pyvista']
for mod_name in MOCK_MODULES:
    sys.modules[mod_name] = MagicMock()
```

I add the files path to `sys.path` to allow autodoc to find them relatively to the docs directory (`sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../../'))`)

1. Regarding the failed numpy import: I am a bit puzzled since it is correctly handled in one of the autodocumented files. So why does this import fail for only two out of three (they all have the same `import numpy as np` statement in their preamble) ? I spent a few hours looking for a similar problem, but only found answers regarding conflicting numpy installations, which I believe I do not have. How do I fix this ?
2. Regarding the Mock error, I tried to follow the lines of https://github.com/seb-m/pyinotify/issues/110 and redefined a few functions for mock, trying to make it accept the multiplication operation:

```
class Mock(MagicMock):
    @classmethod
    def __getattr__(cls, name):
        return Mock()
    def __mul__(self, other):
        return Mock()
    def __rmul__(self, other):
        return Mock()
    def __pow__(self, other):
        return Mock()
    def __div__(self, other):
        return Mock()
```

without any effect. I could get rid of the error by placing this operation in a class or defining it localy where needed, but it is rather anoying this this defines a physical constant that might be used in several classes/functions throughout the module later on. How do I make `mock` accept the multiplication ?

In case this might help, here is the relevant part of the directory structure:

```
--moduleroot/
  |--docs/
  |   |--requirements.txt
  |   |--Makefile
  |   |--make.bat
  |   |--source/
  |   |  |--conf.py
  |   |  |--rstfiles-for-doc
  |   |--build/
  |--module/
  |   |--__init__.py (probably useless?)
  |   |--Module1.py
  |   |--Module2.py
  |   |--Module3.py
  |--setup.py
  |--Manifest.in
```

Thank you in advance, any help would be appreciated at this point since I have no idea what I am doing wrong... (and my apologies if this is too long, since I have no idea of what goes wrong I tried to give as much -relevant- information as possible).

Comment: Does it make any difference if you use `autodoc_mock_imports`? See https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html#confval-autodoc_mock_imports

Comment: Indeed ! This solves the `numpy.core.multiarray` bit, and subsequently clears out all other warnings I had related to it. The only remaining error concerns the mocked multiplication which changed a bit: `hbar_eV = h_eV/(2*np.pi) TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'pi'`

Comment: I can reproduce that error, and it goes away if I use `math.pi` instead of `np.pi`. But I cannot explain why...

Comment: It has to do with the mocking. If numpy is mocked, `np.pi` is not 3.14159....

Comment: Worked like a charm, both locally and on RtD. Thanks a lot ! 
I still find it slightly unsatisfying though. I expected `mock` to behave the same from the autodoc built-in function or manually, and I don't see why mocking a simple arithmetic operation is that complicated. Any pointer to get a clearer view on this is welcome !
I cannot yet upvote this, could you make an answer so I can accept it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This fixed the issues:

- Use the [`autodoc_mock_imports`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html#confval-autodoc_mock_imports) configuration variable to specify modules to be mocked.
- When NumPy is mocked, `np.pi` does not work. `hbar_eV = h_eV/(2*np.pi)` is module-level code that is executed every time Sphinx runs. To get around that, use `math.pi` instead.